# Working with views and revisions

Tags: 7, views

I need to display field data for a given revision in a view for example the body.

To archive this I created a `view` which displays `content revisions`.

This view has a relationship by default: `The revision ID of the content revision.`

I then added the body field using this relation.

When i run the view the body field is empty for all revisions but the active one.

When I change the relation to `The revision NID of the content revision.` I get all fields filled out, but they are all filled with the data from the active revision.

I don't know if this a bug or the expected behavior.

Is there a way to get the field data for revisions that are not active or do I need to rewrite the queries?

I'm using the `revisioning` module, but it doesn't make a difference if it's active or not. The results of the views are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While adding fields to your view, you will see fields named like `Content (historical data) : Field name` select those and you will get the revision data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for.

You don't even need to setup a relation.